# How to append various variables to a .txt file [python]

Tags: python, txt, with-statement

I cant get this code to write anything into the txt file, it is executing but its not writing anything, its also not giving any errors idk what is wrong.

```
    s = "----- Account -----"
    u = "Username: " + username
    p = "Password: " + password
    e = "Email: " + email
    d = "-------------------"
    with open("accounts.txt", "a") as f:
        f.write(s)
        f.write("\n")
        f.write(u)
        f.write("\n")
        f.write(p)
        f.write("\n")
        f.write(e)
        f.write("\n")
        f.write(d)
        f.write("\n")
```

This variables are randomly generated or picked from a txt file it is done with this 3 fuctions

```
def pass_gen():
    chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890!@#$%^&*()_+"
    password = ""
    for c in range(16):
        password += random.choice(chars)
    return password

def user_gen():
    suffix = ['Best', 'Ratchet', 'Baller', 'Big', 'Money']
    name_list = ['Lil', 'Big', 'Young', 'Old', 'Dope', 'Savage', 'Crazy', 'Swag', 'Dank', 'Lit', 'Savage', 'Crazy']
    prefix = ['Swag', 'Dank', 'Lit', 'Savage', 'Crazy']
    
    name = random.choice(suffix) + random.choice(name_list) + random.choice(suffix)
    
    return name

def get_email():
    global emailchoice
    
    with open("email.txt", "r") as f:
        emails = f.readlines()
        tempmail = emails[emailchoice].strip()
    return mail
```

Any fixes or work arounds?

- I tried changing every thing into a variable instead of text
- I tried to use "print()" instead of "file.write"
- I tried to change "file" to "f"
- Tried to change formating of the with statement
- etc.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and [mre]. "it is executing but its not writing anything, its also not giving any errors idk what is wrong." - **how do you know** that it is executing? **How do you know** that it is not writing anything? (That is: exactly which file, **where**, do you expect to change? How did you check for changes?) "I tried to use "print()" instead of "file.write"" -okay, and **what happened** when you tried doing that?

Comment: Which editor or IDE are you using? Perhaps your program is writing to a file in a directory other than the one you intended. (In this case, use a full path: `r'C:\my_files\accounts.txt'`)

Comment: I'm using VS to edit the code and CMD to run the code,  I don't think it is there but I'll make sure to check on e I'm at my PC